# swift : display info to a users (first use) and then disappear

Tags: swift2

I would like to display some info on the screen ... which will disappear.

Example : an Uiview is displayed for the first time to an user (or feature never used by the user). I would like to display on a screen a label or an image to explain how to use this new feature. After that it will disappear ...

If this functionality has already been used by the user, the message is ofcourse not displayed.

example of message --> to add a gamer, press +

---

How to do that ? a lot of apps have this kind of help.

thanks

Comment: You can store a variable with persistant data. When the user use the app for the first time, you display the help, and at this moment change a variable value. Next time the user will come, you check the variable you stored, and if it indicates that the user has already seen the help, you do not display it again

Comment: do you have some examples ?

Comment: I posted an answer, trying to be as comprehensive as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is actually very simple : have a persistent variable, and change its value. Each time the user could see the help popup, you check the value of the variable you stored persistently. If this variable indicates that the user have already seen the help, you don't display it again. Otherwise, you show it. Simple example:

```
let helpSeen: Bool = getVarFromPersistent()
if helpSeen == false {
    // DISPLAY THE HELP MESSAGE OR POPUP
    setHelpSeenVar(true)
}
```

Where `getVarFromPersistent()` and `setHelpSeenVar()` are function you could create to respectively retrieve the variable from the persistent data and set the variable in the persistent data.

Now, you have to figure out how to use persistent data. You can have a look at [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html), that is provided by Apple and "ready to use" in Xcode. You've probably already seen the `use core data` tickbox when you create a project.
Third party libraries exists as well like [RealmSwift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), who reached version 1.0 recently.

I'm not an expert, but I think **Realm** is simpler to use than **Core Data**. The technology used by the two libraries could be different though, maybe someone else could tell you more about it. Anyway, you will find a lot of article about Realm and Core Data on Google.